# Rails serving map tiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, geospatial, rack, passenger

I am building a mapping application in Rails 3. Data for this specific project is static and therefore I have decided to use TileStache to seed my cache and serve the tiles as static images. The issue is that the map data is fairly sensitive and requires authorization. I am using NGinx+Passenger as a web server. The map tiles ranges about 20 kb in size. I have written a proof of concept going directly to rails for authorization and using send_file. Performance is OK. Considering that the files are pretty small I am wondering if the Rack SendFile middleware would help performance in this specific situation. My concerns are current performance and degrading performance as the user base grows. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In my latest implementations I have been using WindShaft. https://github.com/Vizzuality/Windshaft When a user requests a map view in Rails I send back a token which I also store to the Redis db that Windshaft uses. When I request tiles from WindShaft I verify the tokens authenticity in the beforeTileRender callback then supply the tile based on that.